Getting 401 unAuthorized error while implementing SSO in Backend springboot with different kind of JWT token authentication
Implementing SSO with Azure in Spring Boot
I am implementing SSO with Azure for login using Spring Boot, alongside custom token generation and validation.
In this case, I have created a separate bean in the Config file for SSO validation. I am trying to validate specific endpoints with a particular role, admin.
Issue Description
When I use permitAll, I can successfully fetch data from the backend.
However, when I protect an endpoint with hasRole('admin'), I receive a 401 Unauthorized error while hitting the API with a valid JWT token.
Request for Help
Can anyone provide a working solution for this issue?
Thanks in advance!
Azure Verification Configuration
Here is the code setup I am using:
    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/User/Login/**"))
            .authorizeRequests((requests) -> requests
                .antMatchers("/User/Login/details").hasAuthority("admin") // Role    validation
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter()));
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }


General Security Configuration
@Bean
@Order(2)
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
            .antMatchers("/cron/*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(
                "/v3/api-docs", "/swagger-ui/**", "/api-docs", "/swagger-ui.html",
                "/webjars/**", "/swagger-resources/**"
            ).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated())
        .exceptionHandling(ex -> ex.authenticationEntryPoint(point))
        .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
    http.addFilterBefore(filter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    return http.build();
}


JWT Authentication Converter
private JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
    JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter grantedAuthoritiesConverter = new JwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter();
    grantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthorityPrefix(""); // No "ROLE_" prefix
    grantedAuthoritiesConverter.setAuthoritiesClaimName("roles"); // Use "roles" from token claims

    JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(grantedAuthoritiesConverter);

    log.debug("jwtAuthenticationConverter: " + jwtAuthenticationConverter);
    return jwtAuthenticationConverter;
}


Problem Recap
The issue arises when I use hasRole('admin') to protect the /User/Login/details endpoint. While hitting the endpoint with a JWT containing the admin role, the API responds with a 401 Unauthorized error.
If anyone has successfully resolved this type of issue, please share your solution.
Thanks in Advance!
